# netbeans platform old dialog box how to getApplication()

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I'm porting an existing application over to netbeans platform, and while I will probably change some of the existing dialogs to the new notify methods, some of the dialogs are quite complex (multiple panels etc) and I would rather not port them, at least not yet. I found out how to get the mainframe,

```
   mainFrame = (JFrame) WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow();
```

But I have no idea what to use for the .getApplication().show()

```
public void configScoreboard() {
    if (!in_race) {
        if (CSBox == null) {
            CSBox = new SBconfig(mainFrame, true);
            CSBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
        }
        Sst01App.getApplication().show(CSBox);
    }
}
```

The Sst01App of course does not exist in my new Netbeans Platform App and I can't seem to find the app (I think I tried all of the varaibles)

Answer (score 0):

Found it under DialogDescriptor documentation after lots more searching...

https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui_apis/dide/index.html

Where I figured out how to create the custom dialog that I could decorate, The .show() method was still a problem, but I found the DialogDisplayer would work with the object I created. So done.

Dialog sb2Dlg = DialogDisplayer.getDefault().createDialog(sb2);

Still having lots of fun with borderless and full screen, but thats another topic.

```
class MyPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements java.awt.event.ActionListener { 
   //buttons, fields, labels, etc.
    ... 

   public void requestFocus () { //set focus for one components 
        myField.requestFocus (); 
   }
    ...
   public void actionPerformed(final java.awt.event.ActionEvent ap) { // handling code for buttons
    ...
   }
}
MyPanel mp = new MyPanel(); // create new MyPanel 
Object [] options =  {  new JButton ("Choice 1"), 
                    new JButton ("Choice 2")};
DialogDescriptor dd = new DialogDescriptor (mp, 
                        "Text in title", 
                         true, 
                         options, 
                         null, 
                         DialogDescriptor.DEFAULT_ALIGN, 
                         null, 
                         mp); //create new modal DialogDescriptor with defined ActionListener 
mp.requestFocus(); // set focus to component which was specified in MyPanel's         requestFocus() method 
TopManager.getDefault ().createDialog (dd).show (); //show dialog
```